# Object required error in vbscript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I get this error:
[Image](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/2613/greenshot20120713114555.jpg)

When i try to run this code:

```
strComputer = "server01"
strCommand = "powershell.exe -NoLogo -Command Start-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -Computer " & strComputer & " -Name " & strService & ")"

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set objExec = WshShell.Run(strCommand,0,True)
```

I want to run strCommand in an hidden window. This works the code ran through and do what it should do but this error occure and this is really bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Run() - as opposed to .Exec() - returns an error code (not an object). So you must not use

```
Set objExec = WshShell.Run(strCommand,0,True)
```

but

```
nErrorCode = WshShell.Run(strCommand,0,True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a double quote before the command and at its end:

```
strCommand = "powershell.exe -NoExit -NoLogo -Command ""Start-Service -PassThru -InputObject (Get-Service -Computer " & strComputer & " -Name " & strService & ")"""
```